# Browsershot not wroking on Laravel queue

Tags: laravel, docker, browsershot

I have an issue where as I am taking screenshots of responses using Browsershot which works fine when using `dispatchSync`. But as soon as I switch over to dispatch and use the queue (redis) the jobs fail with the following output;

```
Working directory: /var/www/html
Output:
================
Error Output:
================
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT
```

I might also mention this is running through a Docker container.

Comment: Is the same docker container listening and executing REDIS queued jobs? Nothing in laravel or PHP log?

Comment: Yes, horizon is loaded via worker and the same error in the logs

Comment: Is the same linux user running the command from your queue listener, and when you test manually? (eg: root with your test, "php-fpm" with your queue listener). Can you add some details about the Job content? The command that it runs? Ty

Comment: For me, I had to specify the user as `root` just because the other user did not have enough permissions. The error messages are not quite helpful either. Mainly is a permissions issue.